# Prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1+\sin{(n)}}{n} = 0$.

Tags: limits, epsilon-delta

If $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ and $L\in \mathbb{R}$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = L$ if and only if for all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists an $N\in \mathbb{R}$ such that for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ with $n\geq N$ it follows that $|a_n-L| < \epsilon$. Use this definition to prove that
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1+\sin{(n)}}{n} = 0
\end{equation*}
and \begin{equation*}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2n+1}{n} = 2.
\end{equation*}

The second one is simple enough: We have
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\left|\frac{2n+1}{n}-2\right| &= \left|\frac{2n+1-2n}{n}\right| \\
&= \left|\frac{1}{n}\right| \\
&= \frac{1}{n}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
for $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Now for $\epsilon > 0$, $\frac{1}{n} < \epsilon \Longleftrightarrow \frac{1}{\epsilon} < n$. So if we choose any number $N > \frac{1}{n}$, then we have that
\begin{equation*}
n > N \Longrightarrow \left|\frac{2n+1}{n}-2\right| = \frac{1}{n} < \epsilon
\end{equation*}
as required.

The $\sin{(n)}$ term is what is actually baffling me. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Use that $$\left|\frac{1}{n}+\frac{\sin(n)}{n}\right|\le \frac{2}{n}$$ since we have $\left|\sin(n)\right|\le 1$

Answer (score 3):

$|\frac {1+\sin\, n} n| \leq \frac 2 n<\epsilon$ if $n >\frac 2 {\epsilon}$.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers are great. In a more general case, if $f$ is a bounded function, you may want to simplify your expressions by replacing its actual value for the bound, so, knowing $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, (1+\sin(x)) \in (0,2)$:

$|\frac{1+\sin{x}}{n}| \leq \frac{2}{n} \to 0$